# Derive Ref type dynamically, based on rc (ReactElement) prop

Tags: reactjs, typescript, ref

We're working on polymorphic components within a design system.
Im trying to derive the Ref type, dynamically based on the rc prop - inside the following (simplified) example:

```
import React from 'react';
import {
  ComponentPropsWithRef,
  ElementType,
  ReactElement,
  ReactNode,
  Ref,
  useRef,
  cloneElement
} from 'react';

type DomPropsWithDomRef<TElement extends ElementType> = {
  [Key in keyof ComponentPropsWithRef<TElement> as Key extends 'ref'
    ? 'domRef'
    : Key]: ComponentPropsWithRef<TElement>[Key];
};

type BodyProps = {
  rc?: ReactElement<unknown>;
  children?: ReactNode;
}

// @TODO: this isnt quite working right. :thinking_face:
type GetNodeType<T> = T extends ReactElement<any, infer NodeType> ? NodeType : never;

function Body<RC extends ReactElement | undefined>({
  rc = <span />,
  children,
  domRef,
  ...props
}: RC extends undefined
  ? DomPropsWithDomRef<'span'> & BodyProps
  : BodyProps & { rc: RC; domRef?: Ref<GetNodeType<RC>> }) {
  
  return cloneElement(rc, {
    ...props,
    ...(domRef ? { ref: domRef } : {}),
  }, children);
}

function App() {
  const bodyRef = useRef<HTMLSpanElement>(null);
  return <Body domRef={bodyRef} rc={<div />}>some body text</Body> // should error, because domRef should be Ref<HTMLDivElement>
}
```

I'm hoping its possible to derive the `Ref<X>` type dynamically, based on whatever you pass into `rc`. Eg the ref type would be `Ref<HTMLDivElement>` when you do `rc={<div />}`.
Is this possible?

https://tsplay.dev/w1anAw

Comment: The type of rendered JSX does not indicate anything about its content. https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.9.5#code/MYewdgzgLgBAJgSwG4wLwwDyJQegHwBQOOMpMAegPwEGiSwCuANmpszPkSWVTUA

Comment: @AlexWayne So i kinda thought this would be enough type info, no?
https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.9.5#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDG8BmUIjgcilQ3wG4AoctCAOwGd4ATYANzgF44AeZtgegB85PnzhjxEsQD0A-JWr14AVwA2HbqriDho8bMpA

Comment: You're pulling the type from _inside_ the `<>`. If you want to pass JSX then you have to pass the _result_ of the `<>` brackets. And the result of JSX rendered with `<>` is _always_ `JSX.Element`.

Comment: Ohhh right, i see! That makes sense. So i guess its not possible then. :(